# In SwiftUI what is an easy way to align more than one view in ZStack

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-zstack

I have a view and I want to add two icons to it, at top right side and at bottom right side. I managed to do that:

[image]

I used two ZStacks:

```
ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing)
{
    ZStack(alignment: .topTrailing)
    {
        Image(item.thumbnailImage)
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .overlay(Circle()
                        .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 2))
        
        if item.isFavorite
        {
            Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                .offset(x: 7, y: -7)
        }
    }
    
    if item.ordered
    {
        Image(systemName: "checkmark.square.fill")
            .offset(x: 7, y: 7)
    }
}
```

But I have a feeling that there should be a simpler way than nesting ZStacks inside. Besides looks like the small icons don't have their x-centers aligned. I can probably fix that by changing an offset but that would make the code even more clumsy.

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Put the two images in a vstack with a spacer in between

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `overlay` modifier, like this:

```swift
import PlaygroundSupport
import SwiftUI

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(
    Circle()
        .strokeBorder(Color.gray, lineWidth: 6)
        .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
        .overlay(
            Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                .offset(x: 7, y: -7),
            alignment: .topTrailing)
        .overlay(
            Image(systemName: "checkmark.square.fill")
                .offset(x: 7, y: 7),
            alignment: .bottomTrailing)
        .padding()
)
```

[image: a gray circle overlaid by a yellow star at the top right and also overlaid by a checkmark in a black square at the bottom right]

If your deployment target is iOS 15 or later (or an aligned version of macOS, tvOS, or watchOS), you can use the `ViewBuilder` version of `overlay` instead:

```swift
import PlaygroundSupport
import SwiftUI

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(
    Circle()
        .strokeBorder(Color.gray, lineWidth: 6)
        .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
        .overlay(alignment: .topTrailing) {
            Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                .offset(x: 7, y: -7)
        }
        .overlay(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
            Image(systemName: "checkmark.square.fill")
                .offset(x: 7, y: 7)
        }
        .padding()
)
```

We can use lorem's suggestion to align the symbol centers using a `VStack`. Then we can factor out the two `offset` modifiers into a `padding` on the `VStack`.

```swift
import PlaygroundSupport
import SwiftUI

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(
    Circle()
        .strokeBorder(Color.gray, lineWidth: 6)
        .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
        .overlay(
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(.yellow)

                Spacer()

                Image(systemName: "checkmark.square.fill")
            }.padding([.top, .bottom, .trailing], -7),
            alignment: .trailing)
        .padding()
)
```

[image: same as prior image, but now the star and the checkmark are aligned horizontally]

Answer (score 2):

Use only one `Zstack` and wrap the two icons in a `VStack`.

```
        ZStack(alignment: .trailing) {
            Circle()
             .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 2)

            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "checkmark.square.fill")
            }
            // Adjust the position of star and checkmark
            .offset(x: -10)
        }
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
```

[image]